# mysql_num_rows() returns 0 when data present in the database

Tags: php

here is the code which returns 0 instead of 1 and there are already data in the table named REGS

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ67G.png THANKS

Comment: You should echo your query (i.e. $query = "SELECT * FROM..."; echo $query; $qr = mysql_query($query) or die...) and test the resulting query in phpMyAdmin or your MySQL shell of choice. Probably your query has some error.

Comment: Please don't use images to share code.

Comment: Also learn to use prepared statements as it would prevent me from logging in using any random password / username combo

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether the values are properly retrieved. Try this

```
echo $a;
echo $b;
```